# Get usable P12 bundle/private key from Terraform google_service_account_key resource

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, p12

I have created a service account key for a GCP service account using the Terraform `google` provider.  I've set the private key type to `"TYPE_PKCS12_FILE"`, which we require for compatibility with an existing application.

When I was testing this as a PoC, I created the P12 key though the console, and it worked with no issues.  Now, I want to handle key generation in our Terraform script, and I cannot get a working P12 key.  The actual key resource is created, and it contains a `public_key` field, which can be base64 decoded to a valid RSA certificate, and a `private_key`, which is supposedly a P12 file which has been base64 encoded, if I am reading the documentation properly.

I have tried saving the `private_key` value from Terraform into a file, and base64 decoding it manually. It superficially resembles a known valid P12 bundle, but it is reported as an invalid certificate when I try to import it anywhere.

The object in the state looks like:

```
"private_key": "MIIJ[...]GoA==",
"private_key_type": "TYPE_PKCS12_FILE",
"public_key": "LS0t[...]LQo=",
"public_key_data": null,
"public_key_type": "TYPE_X509_PEM_FILE",
```

So, how do I turn the `private_key` from the Terraform resource into a usable P12 file that can be uploaded to our application?

Comment: IIRC the **private_key** value must be base-64 decoded which returns a data structure. Within that data structure is your P12 (PFX) certificate. If you can edit your question with masked details, I will probably recognize what is being returned.

Comment: @JohnHanley You're right.  My error was thinking Terraform could handle the base64 decode.  I used Windows' built-in certutil to decode it instead of trying to do it in TF, and it did work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering this question for myself because the specific error received from Terraform needs some explanation.  If you try to use TF's built-in `base64decode()` function on the private key, it gives the error `"the result of decoding the provided string is not valid UTF-8"`.

I originally assumed that this was an error with the cert, because I had thought that I was expecting the private key to be a PEM certificate, but the `private_key` value actually contains the full P12 bundle.

The basic operation of decoding that string as base64 is correct, but as it turns out, Terraform only supports a limited range of encodings.  Decoding to a P12 bundle is not supported in Terraform, because TF parses the output of the `base64decode()` call to confirm it is valid and it cannot validate the encoding of a P12, since that encoding is not supported.

The solution is to save the output string of the `private_key` property into a txt file, then use a certificate management tool like `openssl` or `certutil` to handle the decoding.

Example:

```
certutil -decode please-decode-me.txt my-mydecoded-cert.p12
```

EDIT: Also, note that at minimum, the encode/decode extensions for VS Code do NOT handle that operation correctly for P12 files.  I tried that approach thinking that those operations would leave the underlying data of the file unchanged and simply parse it again with a different encoding.  This is incorrect, it will change the file data to match the "symbol not found" glyph wherever that glyph is used.

I assume this is well known and/or obvious for security specialists, but I thought I'd explicitly mention it in case it's of use to any other SREs or application devs who don't interact with certificate automation on a regular basis.

Comment: I have a similar issue posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609490/create-p12-keystore-secret-in-tfs-kubernetes-provider

Can you please verify my approach?