# create p12 keystore secret in TF's kubernetes provider

Tags: terraform, p12, terraform-provider-kubernetes

After a lot of struggle and eventually, with the help of this post: I [Get usable P12 bundle/private key from Terraform google_service_account_key resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71325740/get-usable-p12-bundle-private-key-from-terraform-google-service-account-key-reso), it is evident that Terraform doesn't support p12 keystores as such.

**My requirement**:
I am using TF's Kubernetes provider to create a deployment. In that, I have to set a secret using the test.p12 file. Terraform expects files to be UTF-8 encoded. But my p12 Keystore is not UTF-8 encoded. Simple encoding and decoding results in UTF-8 errors.

**My approach**:

1. Encode the p12 keystore using `cat test.p12 | base64 -w0 > encodeout.txt` into a text file that is UTF-8 encoded. Stored it as a terraform variable, encoded_p12.
2. Next, I pass this file below

```
    resource "kubernetes_secret_v1" "test_keystore" {
          metadata {
            name      = "test-keystore"
            namespace = test
          }
          type = "Opaque"
          data = {
            "test.p12" = base64decode(var.encoded_p12)
          }
        }
```

But here it will fail as terraform doesn't decode to a valid p12 file that is UTF-8 encoded.

3. So, first decode the encoded_p12 as below-

```
    resource "local_file" "decodep12" {
        content = var.encoded_p12
        filename = "decoded_p12.p12"
        provisioner "local-exec" {
        command =  "openssl enc -d -base64 -in "${content}" ${filename}" 
          }
        }
```

4. The trying to pass this dynamically created decoded file as

```
    resource "kubernetes_secret_v1" "app_keystore" {
          metadata {
            name      = "test-keystore"
            namespace = test
          }
          type = "Opaque"
          data = {
            "test.p12" = file(${filename})
          }
        }
```

Will this approach work or any corrections in it or any better solution to address it? The limitation is I cannot directly pass the .p12 file to the data block.

Comment: resource "local_file" "decodep12" {
  content = var.encoded_p12
  filename = "${path.module}/decoded_p12.p12"
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command =  "openssl enc -d -base64 -in ${var.encoded_p12} -out ${path.module}/decoded_p12.p12"
    interpreter = ["sh", "-c"]
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_secret_v1" "test_keystore" {
  metadata {
    name      = "test-keystore"
    namespace = test
  }
  type = "Opaque"
  binary_data = {
    "test.p12" = file(local_file.decodep12.filename)
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

There's a much simpler option.

The kubernetes_secret_v1 resource has a binary_data argument for cases like this, which pairs well with the filebase64 function in the Terraform language:

```
    resource "kubernetes_secret_v1" "app_keystore" {
        metadata {
            name      = "test-keystore"
            namespace = "test"
        }
        type = "Opaque"
        binary_data = {
            "test.p12" = filebase64("decoded_p12.p12")
        }
    }
```

Comment: It will decode the decoded_p12.p12 but not as a valid UTF-8 file. Anyways, will try and let you know.